# Angular, could someone please explain the Typescript peerDependencies, tslib 1.* vs 2.3.*

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am creating a new angular project but I don't know how to import the localStorage?

i looking to a existing project using localStorage like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService, LoginModel } from '../_libraries/card-system-core';

export class AuthenticationHelper {
//...
    constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.STORAGE_NAME)));
        this.currentUserRouteSubject = new BehaviorSubject<RouteInfo[]>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.STORAGE_ROUTES_NAME)));

        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
        this.currentUserRoute = this.currentUserRouteSubject.asObservable();
    }
//...
```

the old project was written in typescript, however when I want to use localStroage in my new project, I having the below error
[image]

I expect it will be linked and allow "go to definition" to here
[image]

i manage to find there was a line "peerDependencies" in old package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "tslib": "1.10.0"
  }
```

but it will not get works in my new project if I use

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "tslib": "2.3.0"
  }
```

until i use 1.10.0 under peerDependencies in my project,
my new project setup as below

```
"dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
}
```

My question is why?

i don't know the relationship between Typescript, peerDependencies and tslib

Why i have to config "tslib": "1.10.0" in peerDependencies to get localStorage work?

Is it not a propper way to call/use localStorage by peerDependencies for "tslib": "2.3.0"?

final i revamp my code as below, thanks bro

```
        let storagedName = localStorage.getItem(this.STORAGE_NAME);
        let storagedRouteName = localStorage.getItem(this.STORAGE_ROUTES_NAME);

        let emptyUser:AuthInfo = {
            accessToken: "",
        routes: [],
        twoFA: false,
        forgotPassword: false,
        errorMessage: ""}
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(emptyUser);
        if(storagedName)
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AuthInfo>(JSON.parse(storagedName));

        this.currentUserRouteSubject = new BehaviorSubject<RouteInfo[]>([]);
        if(storagedRouteName)
        this.currentUserRouteSubject = new BehaviorSubject<RouteInfo[]>(JSON.parse(storagedRouteName));
```

Comment: I have no idea why it works with a different version of `tslib`, but the error message is quite clear. You're assigning a variable of type `string | null` to a variable with type `string`. `string` and `null` have no overlap, thus throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is not the package in the peerDependencies.

When you see the error message in vs code it describe you the problem.
The key you use to get the value can be `string` or `null`.
But for localstorage is must be `string`

You can try something like this:

```
if(this.STORAGES_ROUTES_NAME) {
 localStorage.getItem(this.STORAGES_ROUTES_NAME)
}
```

Or if the variable can't be null then you have to change your declaration of the variable.

Maybe the older version of tslib don't control the variable type and that's why it's working.